# TypeORM stack traces: tracing the code that is causing an error in the query through Promises

Tags: node.js, promise, nestjs, typeorm

I am developing an application with NestJS and TypeORM.

When there is an exception in TypeORM query the Node stack trace does not show the code that initiated the query. Is there a way to see which line of code initiated the query that failed? So that I could fix the underlying code that is causing the problem.

Here is an example stack trace that does not show where the query was started

```
QueryFailedError: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "search"
    at new QueryFailedError (/Users/moo/code/token-swap/backend/node_modules/typeorm/error/QueryFailedError.js:11:28)
    at Query.callback (/Users/moo/code/token-swap/backend/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.js:176:38)
    at Query.handleError (/Users/moo/code/token-swap/backend/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:145:17)
    at Connection.connectedErrorMessageHandler (/Users/moo/code/token-swap/backend/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:214:17)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/moo/code/token-swap/backend/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:134:12)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:275:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
```

Comment: My solution was to switch to Python and SQLAlchemy.

Comment: For future visitors --- If anyone got into the same problem, first enable `logging` in the `ormconfig.js` file. that will help you to see which SQL query causing the problem.